# Elasticsearch : Improving multi_match results

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to search a value in a different fields. I am using multi_match with cross_fields type.
Here is the query

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "red cross",
                "type": "cross_fields",
                "fields": [
                  "name^20",
                  "keywords^12",
                  "description^1"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }   }
```

Results I am getting for the above query

```
 "results": [
        {
            "name": "CrossPurpose",
            .....
        } ,
        {
            "name": "Community Center",
            "keywords": "American Red Cross,Red Cross,Center,Blood",
            . . .
          },
          {
             "name": "Some Group",
             "description":".... red cross ..."
          },
          .......
          ....
          ..
          {
             "name" : "Red cross" ,
              .....
          }
          ]
```

I want to improve the search results.

I want to see the record  with name "Red cross" in the first position.
  First it should match as whole word "red cross" then only it should match "red" , "cross".

I want preference to be given more for name field than keywords and description.

Please help me to improve the query .
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use type = [best_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

so your query will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "red cross",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "name", "keywords", "description" ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Whats the use of tie_breaker ? How it is different from using score in the fields

Comment: it take the _score of the best-matching clause, multiply the score of each of the other matching clauses and add them all together.

For more you can check tie_breaker : [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_tuning_best_fields_queries.html]